# How to read data from JSON file with different key and value pairs

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a set of data in a JSON file that consists of UserIDs (as keys) and Passwords (values). I want to read the same using JavaScript for validation purposes. My **JSON** is :

IDsNPass = '[{"A":"A15"},{"B":"B15"},{"C":"C15"}]';

I have an idea about how to access the data using JavaScript as long as the keys in the JSON remain the same. But here, the keys in my JSON are not constant all along. 
Any help on how to get along with the JavaScript is much appreciated!

Comment: JSON is Javascript. You can iterate over JSON keys like any Javascript object, using `for...in`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object

Comment: thank you! @HannesJohansson for your help! cheers! :)

Comment: thank you @MisterHenson for that link, don't know how I could have missed that while searching! Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your design is  not a good format.

If you only have a id-password mapping in on object, you can do like this

```
var ip = JSON.parse(IDsNPass)

for(var obj in ip) {
  for(var key in obj) {
    console.info(key)
    console.info(obj[key])
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your opinion! Any suggestions on what format to save UserNames and Passwords in JSON? @EricZeng

Comment: `json = [{"password": "abcd", "username":"Jhon"}, {"password": "baostu", "username":"Tom"}]`.... then you can do `json.[0].username`

Comment: ....if this is for storing login details on your site,  don't store plain passwords for real users :) ... compare them via MD5 (https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5) or some other hashing strategy in your code

Comment: Following the format that you suggested, I tried the following format for my **JSON** :
json = [{"password": "abcd", "username":"Jhon"}, {"password": "efgh", "username":"Tom"}, {"password": "ijkl", "username": "Julie"}];

And I am trying to access it using **JavaScript** as : 
for(var key in json){
  for(var value in json){
   if(json.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    if(json.hasOwnProperty(value)){
     alert(key + "->" + json[key] + "->" + json[value]);
    }
   }
  }
 }

But this doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas on where im going wrong? @equivalent8

Comment: here you go dude https://jsfiddle.net/dsu6ekwy/     ` for(var key in json){ 
   var user = json[key]
   alert(user.username + " -> " + user.password)
 }
`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @equivalent8 Much Appreciated! Cheers :)